# pjsip link error Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, pjsip

I am trying to build pjsip in Xcode 5 for iOS 7. I have executed all the steps mentioned at
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone.

When I build in Xcode, it gives the following error.

ld: library not found for -lmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove linked `milenage` library or explicitly compile it in since it has been removed by default from pjsip 2.2

see https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1728

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error by searching mileage library and place it in the appropriate directory.

Comment: what is its appropriate directory?